# Dynamically changing Storm Spout instances number and their data sources

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

In my Storm topology I read logs of a running system, so that logs keep changing. However, sometimes, some new log files are being created by side system, and I need to be able to read them too. 
So, if I have a component that keeps track of log files' creations/deletions, can I

- dynamically create/delete instances of spouts
- assign new data sources for spouts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what will the type of new log? will it be just different pattern or will the type of file, directory etc change?

Comment: @vishnuviswanath new log files will have the same structure with similar data

Comment: so why do you need a new spout for this? you can use the same spout. try to parse the message with all your parsers, if unable to parse, it means that the log is different, at this point create a new parser dynamically, based on the incoming message and add the parser to the original list of parses.

Comment: @vishnuviswanath because I need them to be processed in parallel, not one by one, the parser is the same for all of them. I don't have incoming messages - I want to assign one log file per spout, so that it reads file line by line right during it's changed. And when some file created/deleted, instantiate/delete instances of spouts or rebalanse them somehow.

Comment: i don't think it is a good use case for storm. well you can always increase the parallelism of storm spout while setting it to the topology.

Comment: @vishnuviswanath anyway, how do you think, is t possible to assign spouts' data sources dynamically?

Comment: don't think its possible, cause once you submit the topology, the spouts and bolts get serialized and is send to the Nimbus server using thrift client. So if you want to add a spout dynamiclly, this has to be done dynamically and I am not aware if such option is there.